# Relational MySQL query to work out the total cost of an order

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an assignment dealing with relational mysql databases and I'd like to be able to use my tables to do some math. However after creating my tables and attempting various queries I'm starting to think I've messed the relations up. I have four tables, customer, address, orders, and product. My schema is as follows:

[image]

I'm trying to user orders.o_qty to multiply the values in product.p_price and output the totals I have been trying for a while now and either my tables are linked up incorrectly or I'm just not getting it.

`o_qty` in `DDR.orders` is a numerical value, I have been trying to use this value in a query to multiply the value stored in `DDI.product` under `p_price` and output the total value.

Example rows can be found here: [image]

First I have been trying to work out the total then I will progress to modifying this query to work out total per customer.

Comment: You have not made it clear what behavior is correct, so it's hard to answer the question as given (or know exactly what the question is).  Please provide example rows for each table and the expected output you wish to generate.  If you have a SQL query you're trying to use so far, it wouldn't hurt to add that, too.

Comment: So you want just total or total per customer /

Comment: First I have been trying to work out the total then I will progress to modifying this query to work out total per customer.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the data **as text** so that people trying to help you can easily read/copy the values.  Posting data as images makes it harder for people to give you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is could be done with joining the tables.

case 1 : Show total amount per user i.e. total purchased per user without drilling down each product

```
select c.c_id,
c.c_fname,
c.c_lname,
sum(p.p_price) as total 
from orders o 
join customer c on c.cid = o.c_id 
join product p on p.p_id = o.p_id group by c.c_id;
```

Case 2 : Break per product purchased per customer

```
select c.c_id,
c.c_fname,
c.c_lname,
p.p_id,
sum(p.p_price) as total 
from orders o 
join customer c on c.cid = o.c_id 
join product p on p.p_id = o.p_id 
group by c.c_id,p.p_id;
```

Comment: You can use `with rollup` for grand total, just add this after group by clause.